# gerrit not starting with postgres

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-14.04, gerrit

Following these instructions:
    https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.11.4/install.html

Installed postgres 9.3:

```
sudo -i -u postgres
postgres@ubuntu:~$ psql
psql (9.3.10)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

The gerrit2 user cannot access psql, even though I created the user and database

```
postgres@ubuntu:~$ createuser --username=postgres -RDIElPS gerrit2
postgres@ubuntu:~$ createdb --username=postgres -E UTF-8 -O gerrit2 reviewdb

^d
gerrit2@ubuntu:~$ psql
psql: FATAL:  database "gerrit2" does not exist
```

Installed gerrit 2.11.4:

```
gerrit2@ubuntu:~$ java -jar gerrit-2.11.4.war init -d .
```

See gerrit.conf result of install:

```
[gerrit]
        basePath = .
        canonicalWebUrl = http://ubuntu:8080/
[database]
        type = postgresql
        hostname = localhost
        database = reviewdb
        username = gerrit2
[index]
        type = LUCENE
[auth]
        type = OPENID
[sendemail]
        smtpServer = localhost
        smtpUser = lmougen5
[container]
        user = gerrit2
        javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
[sshd]
        listenAddress = *:22
[httpd]
        listenUrl = http://*:8080/
[cache]
        directory = cache
```

gerrit init didn't bring up the browser as per the instructions, so I attempted a reindex.  Note errors in output:

```
gerrit2@ubuntu:~$ java -jar gerrit-2.11.4.war reindex
[2015-11-19 16:42:24,861] INFO  com.google.gerrit.server.git.LocalDiskRepositoryManager : Defaulting core.streamFileThreshold to 119m
[2015-11-19 16:42:25,542] INFO  com.google.gerrit.server.cache.h2.H2CacheFactory : Enabling disk cache /home/gerrit2/cache
Reindexing changes: done    
Reindexed 0 changes in 0.0s (0.0/s)
[2015-11-19 16:42:26,525] WARN  com.google.gerrit.server.cache.h2.H2CacheImpl : Cannot build BloomFilter for jdbc:h2:file:/home/gerrit2/cache/diff_intraline: Error opening database: "Sleep interrupted" [8000-174]
[2015-11-19 16:42:26,526] INFO  com.google.gerrit.server.cache.h2.H2CacheFactory : Finishing 4 disk cache updates
```

Then a restart, probably need to address errors first.  Along with gerrit2 user's access to psql reviewdb:

```
gerrit2@ubuntu:~$ ~/bin/gerrit.sh restart
```

Restart failed, here's ~/logs/error_log:

```
[2015-11-20 08:12:30,627] INFO  com.google.gerrit.server.cache.h2.H2CacheFactory : Enabling disk cache /home/gerrit2/cache
[2015-11-20 08:12:31,970] INFO  com.google.gerrit.server.config.ScheduleConfig : gc schedule parameter "gc.interval" is not configured
[2015-11-20 08:12:33,640] WARN  com.google.gerrit.httpd.GitWebConfig : gitweb not installed (no /usr/lib/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi found)
[2015-11-20 08:12:34,415] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.util.log : Logging initialized @8505ms
[2015-11-20 08:12:35,115] INFO  com.google.gerrit.server.git.LocalDiskRepositoryManager : Defaulting core.streamFileThreshold to 119m
[2015-11-20 08:12:35,204] INFO  com.google.gerrit.server.plugins.PluginLoader : Loading plugins from /home/gerrit2/plugins
[2015-11-20 08:12:35,363] INFO  com.google.gerrit.server.plugins.PluginLoader : Loaded plugin commit-message-length-validator, version v2.11.4
[2015-11-20 08:12:35,479] INFO  com.google.gerrit.server.plugins.PluginLoader : Loaded plugin download-commands, version v2.11.4
[2015-11-20 08:12:35,603] WARN  com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.ReplicationFileBasedConfig : Config file /home/gerrit2/etc/replication.configdoes not exist; not replicating
[2015-11-20 08:12:35,617] INFO  com.google.gerrit.server.plugins.PluginLoader : Loaded plugin replication, version v2.11.4
[2015-11-20 08:12:35,726] INFO  com.google.gerrit.server.plugins.PluginLoader : Loaded plugin reviewnotes, version v2.11.4
[2015-11-20 08:12:35,787] INFO  com.google.gerrit.server.plugins.PluginLoader : Loaded plugin singleusergroup, version v2.11.4
[2015-11-20 08:12:36,290] ERROR com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon : Unable to start daemon
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot bind to *
        at com.google.gerrit.sshd.SshDaemon.start(SshDaemon.java:319)
        at com.google.gerrit.lifecycle.LifecycleManager.start(LifecycleManager.java:74)
        at com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon.start(Daemon.java:293)
        at com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon.run(Daemon.java:205)
        at com.google.gerrit.pgm.util.AbstractProgram.main(AbstractProgram.java:64)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.google.gerrit.launcher.GerritLauncher.invokeProgram(GerritLauncher.java:166)
        at com.google.gerrit.launcher.GerritLauncher.mainImpl(GerritLauncher.java:93)
        at com.google.gerrit.launcher.GerritLauncher.main(GerritLauncher.java:50)
        at Main.main(Main.java:25)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error while binding on 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:22
original message : Permission denied
        at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioSocketAcceptor.open(NioSocketAcceptor.java:238)
        at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioSocketAcceptor.open(NioSocketAcceptor.java:51)
        at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.registerHandles(AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.java:582)
        at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.access$400(AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.java:70)
        at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoAcceptor$Acceptor.run(AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.java:456)
        at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Use documentation for [2.11](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.11.4/install.html) and not 2.0. It became far easier to install.

Comment: Instructions appear to be identical.  Upon more careful review of the installation instructions I noticed that my browser was never forked during install:  "When the init phase is complete, the daemon will be automatically started in the background and your web browser will open to the site:"

Comment: You never wrote that you ran `java -jar gerrit.war init`, but that's what you should run.

Comment: According to your question, `reindex` (instead of `init`) would solve the mentioned problem.

Comment: So new instructions no longer have the schema init, and those are the ones I had previously followed.  The 2.0 instructions are what I found when searching for failures similar to those in my error_log.  Which then made me think I had to do the schema init.  As you state the new instructions are easier, as they no longer require the schema init.  I did run "java -jar gerrit-2.11.4.war init -d ." in my /home/gerrit2 user folder.  Also I did previously run reindex and still couldn't visit http://localhost:8080.  I just re-ran it just now and will append its output to my original issue.

Comment: In reviewing the java stack trace (see reindex output in question above) I see reference to the H2CacheFactory.  Not sure why its playing with H2 when I configured it for PostGres (psql) vs. H2.  I'll append my question with my gerrit.config, showing postgresql vs. H2.

Comment: Opps my psql access from gerrit2, pay attention more closely to error message, was due to trying to access the user name as a database name.  Vs. allowing the user name access to be resolved by the client and simply specifying the database name as the '-d' parameter is meant for:  psql -d reviewdb.  So I'll focus on my sshd configuration issue, which won't even allow me to locally log-in via:  ssh localhost.  I've installed sshd before, not sure why this isn't working at the moment.  Will review the configuration file.

Comment: Uff, you completely changed your question? Please ask a new one next time!

Answer (score 1):

Gerrit runs its own ssh daemon instance and thus must be given its own port separate than any other sshd instances.

The init failure went away once given a unique port, and then the gerrit web site was accessible.

Bad:

```
[sshd]
        listenAddress = *:22
```

Good:

```
[sshd]
        listenAddress = *:29418
```